# Node.js TTL Not working to expire data

Tags: node.js, ttl

Please help, i`m using node.js and mongodb i want to use TTL (Time TO Live) to expire the collection on my database but it does not work and error will show : TypeError: Cannot read property 'createIndex' of undefined and here is my code:
thank in advance

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongodbURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/ex1';
var startDate = new Date();

MongoClient.connect(mongodbURI,setupCollection);

function setupCollection(err, db) {
if(!err) {
console.log("We are connected");
collection=db.collection("test1");
db.test1.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 300 } )

        }
 }
```

Comment: try this `db.collection("test1").createIndex(....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax

```
db.test1
```

to obtain a collection is supported by `mongo` shell, but when using `node.js` driver you have to obtain collection like this:

```
db.collection("test1")
```

so in your case it's like this:

```
db.collection("test1").createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 300 } )
```

[Here is](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/quick-start/#index-a-collection) the relevant docs.